# Trying to identify a font or typeface with a letter "A" shaped like a triangle

Tags: font-identification, logo

I have been trying to find out what font or typeface has a specific shaped letter A, and it has been bugging the hell out of me, maybe you can help.

I've only seen this in 2 places.  One, on a really old book my uncle has on Israel, and the other in the logo for Vernon, New Jersey's Action Park... erm... accident park... :P .

Here's a sample, taken from the Action Park logo:

[image: Action Park logo's letter A]

The fact this specific letter style / shape / shadows / etc. has appeared in more than one place at least has me a little assured that it is not necessarily something created specifically for a company, but I could be very wrong.

Comment: That's such a stylized A and isn't likely legible out of context, it really likely is just drawn that way for that particular logo. Are you *sure* it's the exact figure in both places rather than just similar?

Comment: Dang, I wish I could find the picture I snapped of it, as it looked exactly the same - I otherwise wouldn't bother if it were merely sorta, or very similar, it really was remarkable.

Answer (score 3):

In a case you are 100% sure this is existing font, I will delete this answer, but I afraid there is no such a font. Instead, this is common letter A [customisation](http://www.graphics.com/article-old/font-customization-techniques-sign-logo-creation).

[image]

Comment: It's likely not 'customized' from a source as much as just drawn by hand.

Comment: I guess I should have worded my question sch where also asked in addition "what font could be customized to create what I saw" - heh.

Comment: @travelsonic well, it's a triangle for the most part. :)

Comment: The customized A second from the left in that row of modified letters, funnily enough, looks EXACTLY like what the "A" in the **current** logo for the water park looks like.

Answer (score 3):

The other letters in the logo can be identified as one of the [Univers series](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/univers/), but they have been customised:

[image: Action Park logo]

It's reasonable to say **in this case** that the *A* has been drawn especially, like the final *k,* the dot on the *i* and the capital *P.*

There **are** stylised fonts which feature this form of A, but this isn't one.

Comment: +1, well spotted. Specifically, the [Univers Extended ExtraBlack Oblique](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/univers/93-extra-black-extended-oblique/) cuts are a pretty good [match](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Kzdvh.gif).

Comment: Also, FWIW, the [new logo](http://i.stack.imgur.com/za0hY.png) appears to be based on a Helvetica-like font; WhatTheFont suggests [Nimbus Sans P Black Italic](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/urw/nimbus-sans/black-italic/) as the [closest match](http://i.stack.imgur.com/emdBx.gif).

Comment: I wonder, what stylized fonts do feature that form of A?  Feels like a silly but inevitable question.

Comment: @travelsonic [Answer to inevitable question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/33355/4215)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Ilan's suggestion that this may have been a customized letter from a more ordinary font.  That said, there certainly *are* oddball titling fonts with letter shapes like this, especially among those described as "futuristic" or science-fiction inspired.

For example, here are a few more or less similar examples I found with a quick scroll through myfonts.com:

[[image] Vow](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/thinkdust/vow/)    
[[image] Robofan](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/cepuertas/robofan/)    
[[image] Zolasixx](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typodermic/zolasixx/)    
[[image] Somaton](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/paratype/somaton/)
[[image] Sofachrome](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typodermic/sofachrome/)    
[[image] Recharge](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typodermic/recharge/)    
[[image] Ethnocentric](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typodermic/ethnocentric/)
[[image] Sonic](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/sonic/)    
[[image] Dublon](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/paratype/dublon/)    
[[image] Cortina](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/delve/cortina/)    
[[image] Aquabus](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/t26/aquabus/)
[[image] Asteroid](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/victory/regular/)    
[[image] Stop](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/urw/stop/)    
[[image] Aiko Display](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/thinkdust/aiko/)    
[[image] SF Animatron](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/shyfoundry/sf-animatron/)
[[image] Thrusters](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typodermic/thrusters/)    
[[image] Chilopod](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typodermic/chilopod/)    
[[image] Yacqui](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/jonahfonts/yacqui/)

Fonts like these are also sometimes associated with the 1970s pop culture and video games, perhaps not the least because of the iconic neon-tube inspired [Yagi  Double](http://www.noahharris.co.uk/files/gimgs/PDF/grafik_yagi.pdf) typeface, designed by Robert Trogman c. 1968 and distributed as dry transfer sheets by Letraset:

[image: Yagi Double font]

Comment: Not to go off on a tangent, but I wonder... back when American Airlines had the "[aircraft type] LuxuryJet" and "[aircraft type] LuxuryLiner" decals on their aircraft, was said decal a mix of Yagi Double and Helvetica? (I mean, the Yagi Double for the aircraft type (757, 767, A300, MD-11, DC-10, etc), Helvetica for the "LuxuryJet" and "LuxuryLiner" part)

Comment: @travelsonic: Based on [this photo](https://www.flickr.com/photos/28042007@N07/3364271951/in/gallery-cameliatwu-72157622491322448/), I'd say it's similar, but not quite the same; the 7 looks very close, but the 5 has some obvious differences, like the hook at the bottom end and the fact that the white centerline doesn't seem to stay at the center.

Comment: Hmmm.  I wonder... is it a different but similar type, or customized letters like with the logo that spurred my initial question.

Comment: Zolasixx's A looks almost perfect - to customize it to match the "A" in the logo, it looks as if you just need to truncate the extra bit trailing below the rest of the letter.  Could it be a good guess at least to say the "A" in the Action Park logo is likely that?

Comment: Pardon double-posting, but re: the American Airlines LuxuryJet/LuxuryLiner decals:
Remember, on the safety cards from the early 80s through the early 90s, they had the aircraft type and LuxuryJet or LuxuryLiner on them, looks like it is the same typefaces as on the decal.
757:
http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTYwMFgxMjY4/z/jmgAAOxyQfJTfcHD/$_57.JPGhttp://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTYwMFgxMjY4/z/jmgAAOxyQfJTfcHD/$_57.JPG
Super 80:
http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/ODc4WDYzOA==/$(KGrHqZHJDoE9B!-F,CUBPZlHvv-Dg~~60_57.JPG
767-323:
http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTYwMFgxMjg1/z/suMAAOxy63FS9iMo/$_12.JPG

Answer (score -1):

Visit click here, maybe this font is identical to what you mean https://www.dafont.com/earth-orbiter.font?text=A+P

Answer (score -5):

The font is Recharge.

[image]

You can download it here:
http://www.dafont.com/recharge.font?text=zolasixx

My dad found it in a minute, but he's a computer teacher so it's ok.

Comment: Not the same font. It is a triangle font but not identical.